# For convex $ABCD$, with $H\in AB$ and $G\in AD$ such that $CH\parallel AD$ and $CG\parallel AB$, and $E=BG\cap HD$, prove $S_{AHEG}=S_{HBCD}$

Tags: geometry, triangles

> Given convex $\square ABCD$, and $H\in (AB)$ and $G\in (AD)$ such that $(CH)\parallel(AD)$ and $(CG)\parallel(AB)$, define $E=(BG)\cap(HD)$. Prove that: 
>   $$S_{AHEG}=S_{HBCD}$$
>   (where $S$ denotes area).

My try:

We know that: $AHCG$ is parallelogram. For example area $S_{AHCG}=2z$.Connect $[HG],[EC],[EA]$. Then $S_{AHE}+S_{ECG}=z$ also $S_{HCE}+S_{EGA}=z$

From here I don't know how I complete?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be true. Also, what does $(CH)//(AD)$ mean?

Comment: @bjonr93 its  Parallel line

Comment: The result is not correct as stated. Take a degenerate case with $C$ the midpoint of $\overline{BD}$, $|AB|=|AD|$, and $\angle A = 90^\circ$; that is, $\square ABCD$ coincides with isosceles right triangle $\triangle ABD$. Then $H$ and $G$ are the midpoints of $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{AD}$, and $E$ is the triangle's centroid. Then $HBCD$ coincides with $\triangle HBD$ and fills half of $\triangle ABD$; however $AHEG$ is a quadrilateral that does not fill the other half of $\triangle ABD$ (that is, $\triangle AHD$). The areas are not equal.